# How to publish ports in user defined network in rootless podman?

Tags: networking, containers, podman

I'm trying to publish ports to host from the container, but it does not work when the container is being run with the user defined network. See below:

```
$ podman network create samplenet
$ podman network ls              
NAME       VERSION  PLUGINS
samplenet  0.4.0    bridge,portmap,firewall,tuning,dnsname
$ podman run -dt --name test --network=samplenet --rm --publish 8080:80 nginx
$ podman port -l   
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8080
$ curl localhost:8080
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I've noticed that network mode for containers without network specified is `slirp4netns`, but when I specify a network it is changed to: `bridge`.

How can I expose ports from the container and connect it to the user-defined network in rootless mode?

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug in podman 3.0.1. Fixed in 3.1.0.

https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/9532